# PHPMailer Form Help

Tags: php, forms, formatting, spam-prevention, phpmailer

Is there any better way to stop spam coming through on my phpmailer script?

Also how would I go about adding formatting to this so its more readable when it gets sent through to email e.g. break lines

I hope my php syntax is correct - as i do not understand PHP.

```
<?php
        # bool has_injection (String $var, [String $var, ...])
        function has_injection () {
            $values = func_get_args();
            for ($i=0, $count=func_num_args(); $i<$count; $i++) {
                if ( stristr($values[$i], "%0A") || stristr($values[$i], "%0D") || stristr($values[$i], "\\r") || stristr($values[$i], "\\n") 
                    || stristr($values[$i], "Bcc") || stristr($values[$i], "Content-Type") ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        $error = '';
        if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0) {
            # The form has been submitted
                $course_title = $_POST['course_title'];
                $course_date = $_POST['course_date'];
                $course_code = $_POST['course_code'];
                $course_fee = $_POST['course_fee'];
                $break .= "\n";
                $qual_subject_level = $_POST['qual_subject_level'];
                $break .= "\n";
                $email = $_POST['email'];

            if ($name && $email && $subject) {
                if (has_injection($name, $email, $subject)) {
                    # You've got another spammer at work here
                    $error = 'No spamming';
                    exit(0);
                }
                else {
                    # It's safe to send the message
                    mail('my@gmail.com', 
                    $subject,
                    $course_title, 
                    $course_code, 
                    $course_fee,
                    $break,
                    $qual_subject_level,
                    $break,
                    $subject,
                    "From: $name <$email>");
                }
            }
            else {
                $error = 'Please fill in all the forms';
            }
        }


    ?>
```

Comment: just as a note, if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0) { is breakable with one button on a page that sends data to your self best having check for every field. you can tehn use regex to make sure there using a valid email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One i use is have a text area and use your .css file to display:none it most bots dont read the css and thus think that the text box is shown and if it has content in it it's a bot if it does not then send your email.

E.G CSS
`.antiBot{display:none};`

HTML
`<input type="text" class="antiBot" name="antibot" value="" />`

PHP

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['antibot'] == ""){
  // send your email
}else{
  // bot using your system
}
?>
```

How ever change the name or bot will get be able to notice its a trap and will get around it with little work insted of having to parse the CSS file for your site

So in your case just rap the if above around your code as for formatting of an email if its plain text use dubble quotes and \n (newline) but it wont work in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks @Barkermn01, i'll try that. Do you know of anyway to make the sendform display as HTML when the form processes so I can set a font type? or is this more complicated?

Comment: it's quite complicated but there are classes that will let you do both HTML and Text fallback http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1685-PHP-Compose-and-sent-text-and-HTML-e-mail-messages.html

Comment: Thanks alot! I've never heard of phpclasses looks like a good resource.

Comment: i have a few codes on there my self google "lightweight MVC" and mine on phpClasses is top link